# Open element in Accordion based on ID - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple *jQuery Accordion* on my website.

Within each element, there are `<span>` elements with unique IDs.

So... if I click `/gallery#football` it should open the 2nd block in my Accordion.

Is this possible?

[My Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/10/).

**Javascript**

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    var allLinks = $('a.heading');
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        //Remove all 
        allLinks.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

        //Add active class
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });
    $('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<dl class="accordion">
<dt><a href="" class="heading">Tester</a></dt>
<dd>
    <span id="tester"></span>
    <span id="anothertester"></span>
    <p>bla</p>
</dd>

<dt><a href="" class="heading">Sports</a></dt>
<dd>
    <span id="football"></span>
    <span id="basketball"></span>
    <p>bla</p>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `find()` and `parent()` or `closest()` functions:

```
// Get id from url
var url = window.location.pathname;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#')); // This will give you #football

var spanTag = $('.accordion').find(id); //#football span tag
var parentTag = spanTag.closest('dd');

//open the accordion
...
```

The best way is to create a new function for this:

```
function setAccordion() {
    // Get id from url
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#')); // This will give you #football

    var spanTag = $('.accordion').find(id); //#football span tag
    var parentTag = spanTag.closest('dd');

    //open the accordion
    ...
}

// Call the function
setAccordion();
```

**Working DEMO in jsfiddle:**

You can test it also to change the `#football` id by eg `#tester`, which opens the first accordion.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/11/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you possibly look at my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/10/ and explain exactly where I should make this change? Many thanks :-)

Comment: can you possibly show me how this integrates into the code in my Fiddle? Thank you

Comment: Many thanks - I will test shortly - very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Excellent, this works! However, what if I want to link to `#rugby`, currently that doesn't work.

Comment: because there is no tag inside the accordion with rugby

Comment: Aaah OK :-) How would I allow this for `rugby` and other sports?

Comment: just add them to the html code that's all, even if you create a new  heading this code will work: see fiddle with only new html code added http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/12/

Comment: My apologies. I can be bad at explaining things :-) I would like it to work for both `football` & `rugby`. Is this possible? :-)

Comment: this will be a new question, please accept this one and ask a new question where you wan't to open 2 accordion elements

Comment: Thank you @VDesign - here is my new question :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246084/anchor-link-to-multiple-locations-using-jquery